# How can I fix my install of ReactiveCocoa (with CocoaPods)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, installation, cocoapods, reactive-cocoa

Newbie here, trying to install ReactiveCocoa 2.2.4 with CocoaPods into a project and running into errors at runtime. I have used [this podspec on github](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/8feda1f6d8636dcbd423b48d377a17c59c84ae53/ReactiveCocoa/2.2.4/ReactiveCocoa.podspec). Here's my code --

MainViewController.m @interface has:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *testString;
```

MainViewController.m viewDidLoad() has:

```
self.testString = @"hello";
[RACObserve(self, testString) subscribeNext:^(NSString *newString) {
    NSLog(@"%@", newString);
}];
self.testString = @"yellow";
```

This is the runtime error I get, where it looks as though "self" is getting the selector sent to it instead of "testString":

exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainViewController rac_valuesForKeyPath:observer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

FWIW, I have been able to successfully install ReactiveCocoa via CocoaPods twice in two fresh xcode projects following [this youtube vid](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-Ir_tRho2w) -- both with and without the podspec i'm trying to use in my other project.

More info about my setup:

- Xcode 5
- In Target: General: Linked Libraries and Frameworks: libPods.a (in black -- weirdly, in the new projects where ReactiveCocoa works, this is red)
- In Target: Build Settings: Other Linker Flags: -ObjC and -all_load (even though my understanding is that adding these is no longer necessary. also, whether I have them or not, i still get the same result).
- In Target: Build Settings: Header Search Paths: (all non-recursive, all added by CocoaPods):
  "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers", "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/ReactiveCocoa", "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa"
- In Target: Build Phases: Target Dependencies: nada (do I need something here?)
- In Target: Build Phases: Link Binary With Libraries: : libPods.a (in black -- weirdly, in the new projects where ReactiveCocoa works, this is red)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: As a workaround, I ended up creating a new project, installing ReactiveCocoa, and then porting the original project code/storyboard/etc over, which was not ideal but actually went pretty quickly. Though I now have a working version of ReactiveCocoa, I'd still be curious to know what i could have done to my abandoned project/workspace to make it work, if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: Looks like XCode stuck with corrupted data.
1. Clean build. 2. Close project. 3. Remove derived data. 4. cmd-Clean project folder.