# ReactiveCocoa - not working on existing project

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I've referred to [How can I fix my install of ReactiveCocoa (with CocoaPods)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947533/how-can-i-fix-my-install-of-reactivecocoa-with-cocoapods) but it hasn't helped. Basically, if I make a new project and carry out these steps:

```
1) sudo gem install cocoapods
2) pod init
3) Change Podfile to 

# platform :ios, ‘8.0’
target 'Test Project' do
pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
end
4) pod install
```

It works perfectly.

However, when I try to do it on my current project in the example below, it doesn't work..

in .h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *testString;
```

in viewDidLoad..

```
self.testString = @"hello";
[RACObserve(self, testString) subscribeNext:^(NSString *newString) {
    NSLog(@"%@", newString);
}];
self.testString = @"yellow";
```

I receive the error log:

```
2015-04-23 16:13:49.386 MyProjectName[69489:1451941] -[PlayViewController rac_valuesForKeyPath:observer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f987b4a0010
2015-04-23 16:13:49.443 MyProjectName[69489:1451941] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PlayViewController rac_valuesForKeyPath:observer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f987b4a0010'
```

I saw that he ended up just porting it over to a working project which shouldn't be necessary. Any help / questions would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding `$(inherited)` in `Build settings`, Levels to `Other Linker flags`, Debug & Release.